# Find equation of parabola given two points and known area under curve

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, area

I have a parabola that passes through two points: $(0,50)$ and $(10, 10)$. I also know that the area under the curve, between these two points, is $300$.

Is there a method by which I might find equations that satisfy these requirements?

Thanks much!

---

P.S. Would it be accurate to rewrite these givens in the form:
$f(0) = 50$, $f(10) = 10$, and $\int_{0}^{10} f(x)\, dx = 300$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "under the curve"?  Roughly having had plotted the 2 points, it appears that the parabola opens downward.  So does under the curve mean "between the curve and the x-axis (aka, y=0)?

Comment: You appear to have an unstated assumption that the parabola’s axis is parallel to the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f\left( x \right) =a{ x }^{ 2 }+bx+c\\ f\left( 0 \right) =50\Rightarrow c=50\\ f\left( 10 \right) =100a+10b+50=10\quad \Rightarrow \quad 10a+b=-4$$
Now solve system equations to find $a$ and $b$ $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 10 }{ \left( a{ x }^{ 2 }+bx+50 \right) dx=300 } \\ 10a+b=-4$$